# Problem running MVC3 app in IIS 7

Tags: iis-7.5, asp.net-mvc

I am having a problem getting a MVC 3 project running in IIS7 on a computer running Windows 7 Home-64 bit.  Here is what I did.

1. Installed IIS 7.
2. Accessed the server and got the IIS welcome page.
3. Created a directory named d:\MySite and copied the MVC application to it. (The MVC app is just the standard app that is created when you create a new MVC3 project in visual studio.  It just displays a home page and an account logon page.  It runs fine inside the Visual Studio development server and I also copied it out to my hosting site and it works fine there)
4. Started IIS management console.
5. Stopped the default site.
6. Added a new site named "MySite" with a physical directory of "d:\Mysite"
7. Changed the application pool named MySite to use .Net Framework 4.0, Integrated pipeline

When I access the site in the browser I get a list of the files in the d:\MySite directory.  It is as if IIS is not recognizing the contents of d:\MySite as an MVC application.

What do I need to do to resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since IIS was installed after .NET 4, you likely need to run the [aspnet_regiis.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h.aspx) tool to register all the .NET 4 stuff with IIS.